# Case insensitive string search is not working

Tags: javascript, html, web

Please have a look at the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script>
function count()
{
    var listOfWords, paragraph, listOfWordsArray, paragraphArray;
    var wordCounter=0;

    listOfWords = document.getElementById("wordsList").value;

    //Split the words
    listOfWordsArray = listOfWords.split("\n");

    //Convert the entire word list to upper case
    for(var i=0;i<listOfWordsArray.length;i++)
    {
        listOfWordsArray[i] = listOfWordsArray[i].toUpperCase();
    }

    //Get the paragrah text
    paragraph = document.getElementById("paragraph").value;
    paragraphArray = paragraph.split(" ");

    //Convert the entire paragraph to upper case
    for(var i=0; i<paragraphArray.length; i++)
    {
        paragraphArray[i] = paragraphArray[i].toUpperCase();
    }

    //check whether paragraph contains words in list
    for(var i=0; i<listOfWordsArray.length; i++)
    {
    /*  if(paragraph.contains(listOfWords[i]))
        {
                wordCounter++;
        }*/

        re = new RegExp("\\b"+listOfWordsArray[i]+"\\b");

        if(paragraph.match(re))
        {
            wordCounter++;
        }
    }

    window.alert("Number of Contains: "+wordCounter);
}
</script>

</head>


<body>
<center>
<p> Enter your Word List here </p>
<br />
<textarea id="wordsList" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>

<br />
<p>Enter your paragraph here</p>
<textarea id="paragraph" cols="100" rows="15"></textarea>

<br />
<br />
<button id="btn1"  onclick="count()">Calculate Percentage</button>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, what I am trying to do is counting how any number of words are in `paragraph` which are also included in `wordList`. words in `wordList` are separated by new line.

However I need this check to be case insensitive. for an example, there should be no difference between 'count' , 'COUNT' and 'Count'.

But here, I am always getting the answer 0. What am I doing wrong here?

### Update

I tried the following function, provided by SO User 'Kolink'. However it is giving different answers in different runs. In first few runs it was correct, then it starts to provide wrong answers! Maybe JavaScript as `static` variables?

Comment: You should uppercase the value before splitting it. This will allow you to remove the first two loops.

Comment: Do you want to count how many words from the list appear in the paragraph, or how many _times_ the words appear?

Comment: @Mathletics: This should analyze the paragraph and tell you what percentage of the words in the paragraph are contained within the word list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are preparing the paragraph's words in `paragraphArray` but then you never use it.

I would suggest something like this:

```
var words = document.getElementById('wordsList').value.split(/\r?\n/),
    l = words.length, i, total = 0, para = document.getElementById('paragraph').value;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) if( para.match(new RegExp("\\b"+words[i]+"\\b","i"))) total++;
alert("Total: "+total);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated my question, please have a look

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. It seems like the web browser maintained a cache copy, or get confused when the same file is open in number of tabs

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

How about just this:

```
var wc = function (text, wordsToMatch) {
  var re = new RegExp("(" + (wordsToMatch || ["\\w+"]).join('|') + ")", "gi");
  var matches = (text || "").match(re);

  // console.log(matches);
  return (matches ? matches.length : 0);
};
```

Or for an unreadable version (not recommended):

```
var wc = function (t, w) {
  return (((t || "").match(new RegExp("(" + (w || ["\\w+"]).join('|') + ")", "gi")) || []).length);
};
```

## Integration

So, in your code, you'd be able to throw away most of it and write:

```
function count()
{
    var wordsList   = document.getElementById("wordsList").value;
    var paragraph   = document.getElementById("paragraph").value;
    var wordCounter = wc(paragraph, wordsList.split("\n"));

    window.alert("Number of Contains: " + wordCounter);
}
```

## Examples

### Example 1 (matches against a list)

**Input:**

```
console.log(wc("helloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworld", ["world"]));
console.log(wc("helloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworld", ["hello", "world"]));
```

**Output:**

```
12
24
```

### Example 2 (safe defaults)

**Input:**

```
console.log(wc("", ["hello", "world"]));
console.log(wc());
console.log(wc(""));
```

**Output:**

```
0
0
0
```

### Example 3 (as a default word counter)

**Input:**

```
console.log(wc("hello"));
console.log(wc("hello world"));
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could search with no regexp ([link to `eliminateDuplicates`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/840849/1636522)) :

```
var wordCounter = 0;

// retrieves arrays from textareas

var list = eliminateDuplicates(
    document.getElementById('wordsList').value
    .toUpperCase()
    .split(/\s+/g)
);
var para = eliminateDuplicates(
    document.getElementById('paragraph').value
    .toUpperCase()
    .split(/\s+/g)
);

// performs search

for (var i1 = 0, l1 = para.length; i1 < l1; i1++) {
    var word = para[i1];
    for (var i2 = 0, l2 = list.length; i2 < l2; i2++) {
        if (list[i2] === word) {
            wordCounter++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

your regex is not well formatted.
try

```
re = new RegExp("\\b"+listOfWordsArray[i]+"\b\");
```

cause the first caracter is \ , so the last should be \ , and not b

Comment: the RegExp constructor takes a string.